# MYSQL If Condition to not display if then value is 0

Tags: mysql, sql

What i have is the Query

```
SELECT
    mm.module_id, mm.module_name,
    pm.permission_id, pm.permission_name,
    CASE WHEN rp.permission_id is not null
        THEN false ELSE true END AS status
FROM permission_master AS pm 
LEFT OUTER JOIN role_permission AS rp
    ON pm.permission_id = rp.permission_id AND rp.RoleID = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN module_master AS mm
    ON pm.module_id = mm.module_id
ORDER BY mm.module_id, pm.permission_id
```

[Here is the Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a960/1)

**It returns the Values and the Status will be as 0 and 1 according to the given condition in the Query.**

**What i need is it should not return the coloumns that is with the Status 0**

How can i do this ?

Comment: If you dont want to display the 0 status then add `having status = 1` before the order by clause.

Comment: Awesome.. It works like great !! Please post is an answer to accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to add the having clause as
`having status = 1` before the order by clause

```
select
mm.module_id, 
mm.module_name, 
pm.permission_id, 
pm.permission_name, 
case 
when rp.permission_id is not null then false 
else true 
end as status 
from permission_master as pm 
left outer join role_permission as rp on pm.permission_id = rp.permission_id and rp.RoleID = 1 
left outer join module_master as mm on pm.module_id = mm.module_id 
having status = 1
order by mm.module_id, pm.permission_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a960/2

Answer (score 1):

You can add a where clause in your query like below

```
select mm.module_id, mm.module_name, pm.permission_id, 
pm.permission_name, 
case when rp.permission_id is not null then false else true end as status 
from permission_master as pm 
left outer join role_permission as rp on pm.permission_id = rp.permission_id 
and rp.RoleID = 1 
left outer join module_master as mm on pm.module_id = mm.module_id 
where rp.permission_id is null
order by mm.module_id, pm.permission_id
```